# How to store a Python list to an excel file?

Tags: python-3.x, excel, list

I have a Python list which has 6000 sub-lists. How do I make each of those sub-lists as a row in a single excel file?
For example
ls = [[1,2,3], [3,4,5]].
How do I make an excel file where first row is 1,2,3 and the second row is 3,4,5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a CSV file from the list. For example:

```py
import pandas as pd

ls = [[1, 2, 3], [3, 4, 5]]

df = pd.DataFrame(ls)
df.to_csv("data.csv", index=False, header=False)
```

Produces `data.csv`:

[image]

---

Or with built-in `csv` module:

```py
import csv

ls = [[1, 2, 3], [3, 4, 5]]

with open("data.csv", "w") as f_out:
    writer = csv.writer(f_out)
    writer.writerows(ls)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to create an `.xlsx` file you can use **[xlsxwriter](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/)**:

```
import xlsxwriter

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('data.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

ls = [[1,2,3], [3,4,5]]

for row_index, row in enumerate(ls):
    for col_index, val in enumerate(row):
        worksheet.write(row_index, col_index, val)

workbook.close()
```

**Output:**

[image: excel output]